# Sorting list of tuples going wrong

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python. Been reading alot and now I want to solve problems. I am trying to solve every solution I can on DailyProgrammer(reddit).

Anyway, I am having a problem. I am trying to sort a list of tuples after the second value. And it works just fine except for one thing. One of the values that is supposed to be first in the list ends up last.

```
class UserTime(object):

    def __init__(self, user, time):
        self.user = user
        self.time = time

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.user,
                                  self.time)
user_time_list = [ 
    UserTime('UserA', '41.04'), 
    UserTime('UserB', '7.06'), 
    UserTime('UserC', '20.63'), 
    UserTime('UserD', '54.28'), 
    UserTime('UserE', '12.59'), 
    UserTime('UserF', '31.17'), 
    UserTime('UserG', '63.047') ]

print(user_time_list)
print
print(sorted(user_time_list, key=lambda user: user.time))

Output:

[UserA: 41.04, UserB: 7.06, UserC: 20.63, UserD: 54.28, UserE: 12.59, UserF: 31.17, UserG: 63.047]

[UserE: 12.59, UserC: 20.63, UserF: 31.17, UserA: 41.04, UserD: 54.28, UserG: 63.047, UserB: 7.06]
```

I have been trying every technique online. Searching on google. Even the gettattribute functions. I have also tried doing this solution without making a class and just making a simple list of tuples. Same problem... UserB ends up last. And that's wrong, because he is clearly the winner ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting strings. That means they get sorted by the lexicographic order.
In that order, `.` is behind the numbers.

You want to make the numbers in the list floats which do get numerically compared:

```
user_time_list = [ 
    UserTime('UserA', 41.04), 
    UserTime('UserB', 7.06), 
    UserTime('UserC', 20.63), 
    UserTime('UserD', 54.28), 
    UserTime('UserE', 12.59), 
    UserTime('UserF', 31.17), 
    UserTime('UserG', 63.047) ]
```

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. You can mark an answer as 'this solved my problem' by clicking the check mark on the left.

Comment: Haha thanks. I will be keeping you guys busy from now on. Especially when I jump to the medium and hard problems on Dailyprogrammer. ;)